# How to get a system environment variable as a value in catalina.properties

Tags: windows, tomcat

I am trying to set a sysprop for tomcat to use in an xml configuration.

How can I use system environment variables in the catalina.properties file?

When I call ${computer.name} it resolves to %COMPTUERNAME%. How can I get it to resolve to the computername environment variable?

Heres the snippet in catalina.properties:

```
computer.name=%COMPUTERNAME%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67214216/how-to-set-org-apache-tomcat-util-digester-environmentpropertysource-in-tomcat)