# how to set org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, kubernetes

I want to set environment variables via Kubernetes for server.xml in tomcat. Here is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: tomcat-test-pod
...
...
env:
  - name: hostName
    value: 'test.com'
  - name: localhost
    value: 'localhost.com'
```

And here is my server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Resource 
      auth="Container" 
      description="Global E-Mail Resource" 
      mail.debug="false" 
      mail.smtp.auth="false" 
      mail.smtp.ehlo="true" 
      mail.smtp.host="${hostName}"
      mail.smtp.localhost="${localhost}"  
      mail.smtp.port="25" 
      mail.smtp.sendpartial="true" 
      mail.transport.protocol="smtp" 
      name="mail/Session" 
      type="javax.mail.Session"/>
```

From https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/systemprops.html, it says that I need to set `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester. PROPERTY_SOURCE` to `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource`, but I am not sure what I am supposed to do. Do I need to set it in setenv.sh or do I need to create another class? Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE` is a Java system property so you can set it where system properties are accepted:

- you can add it to the command line options, e.g. by adding to `setenv.sh`:

```sh
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource
```

This will work only if you call `catalina.sh/startup.sh` to start Tomcat (directly or indirecly). For example it will not work on Windows, when starting Tomcat as a service.

- add the system property to `catalina.properties`:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource
```

This always works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One quick question. If I use `catalina.sh run`, would it still work for second part of your answer?

Comment: Yes, `catalina.properties` is loaded by the Java code, so no matter how you start your server, it will always be loaded. On the other hand the `setenv.sh` script is only sourced by other scripts, so it can be omitted on some systems.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Just one more question.. I am thinking about creating `setenv.sh` instead of touching properties file. All I need to do is to create (I don't have setenv.sh file in my base tomcat image) `setenv.sh` and start tomcat? I can't try this yet because I am not sure how to check if server.xml placeholders are replaced with environment variables (server.xml file is not ready) @Piotr P. Karwasz

Comment: Yes, `setenv.sh` doesn't usually exist and you need to create it in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin` or `$CATALINA_HOME/bin` (`/usr/local/tomcat/bin` in the DockerHub images). To test the replacement you can change the access log path for example.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it in my test configuration with setenv.sh with this `CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource"` and then ran tomcat, I get this exception: `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit> Unable to load property source[org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource].` Do you happened to know what I am doing wrong here? I apologize for keep asking questions..

Comment: Same here - `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.EnvironmentPropertySource` and `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource`.