# tomcat server.xml environment variable using setenv.sh throw exception

Tags: java, tomcat, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to set some values in server.xml using environment variables. From this [how to set org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67214216/how-to-set-org-apache-tomcat-util-digester-environmentpropertysource-in-tomcat), I create setenv.sh file in /tomcat/bin with this:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource"
```

When I run tomcat, I get this exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit> Unable to load property source[org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource].
```

I am really new to tomcat, so I have no idea what it means. I am not sure even if it is related to the `setenv.sh`. I don't see the same exception without `setenv.sh` file. I tried to research on this topic, but not many information was found.

Can anyone please answer why this is happening?

EDIT: here is my whole stack trace from the log file

```
26-Apr-2021 19:32:44.857 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit> Unable to load property source[org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource].
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit>(Digester.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.createStartDigester(Catalina.java:272)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:528)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:644)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

26-Apr-2021 19:32:44.859 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit> Unable to load property source[org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource].
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit>(Digester.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.createStartDigester(Catalina.java:272)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:528)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:644)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
```

Comment: Your logs (`catalina.<date>.log`) should contain more information on why Tomcat failed to load the `EnvironmentPropertySource`. Can you add the to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource` class is available since [Tomcat 7.0.108](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_7.0.101_(violetagg)), [Tomcat 8.5.65](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.5.52_(markt)) and [Tomcat 9.0.45](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.32_(markt)). You must be running an older release.

Comment: Thanks. I just found that this class is not available from 8.5.0 to 8.5.51 for some reason (from tomcat github). Besides updating tomcat version, is there any other option for me? (https://github.com/apache/tomcat/tree/8.5.51/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/digester)

Comment: Since the last [security vulnerability](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-8.html) was corrected in 8.5.63, the best option is to upgrade: you just need to replace the old jars with the new ones. The class didn't exist before 8.5.46 (cf. the links to the release notes in the answer).